# How to analyzing this algorithm with justification

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Is the following claim true? Why?

> `C(n) = log2(nn)` implies that `c(n)` is `THETA(log n)`

Comment: What's C(n) and c(n)?

Comment: `log(n^n) = n log n`, which definitely is not in `Θ(log n)`

Comment: Is `C(n)=c(n)`, or are those two different functions?

Comment: @blender, how would I prove that math wise?>

Comment: @user3563184: Use the definition of a function `f` being in `Θ(g)`. You'll get a contradiction immediately.

Answer (score 1):

No, the claim is wrong. (assuming `C(n)=c(n)`, and that's just a typo).

```
C(n) = log_2(n^n) = n*log_2(n) = nlog(n)
```

Since `nlog(n)` is NOT in `Theta(logn)`, the claim is false, and in fact `C(n)` is in `Theta(nlogn)`.

Comment: Thats how the question is stated. Its not a typo. Its asking if log2(n^n) is the same as THETA(log n).

Comment: @user3563184 Then the answer is no, and I provided the explanation for it.